# How to detemine field of struct is zero value by initialize or not?

Tags: go, struct

I have some condition where to make a dynamic query, value is not set will be ignore. But I have confused how to determine the value is zero value is by input(user) or not (golang set for us)

example :

```
type User struct {
  Age int
}
user := User{ Age : 0 } // query := `Where age = ... ` 
user := User{} // query := ``
```

I have use pointer and json before, it's work but in this case i cannot change the struct structure.

```
type User struct {
  Age *int `json:"age"`
}
user :=User{}
if user.Age == nil { //not set }
```

is anyone can give me idea or keywords? Thanks

Comment: if you cannot change the struct def then there s no solution imho.

Comment: so set struct field to pointer is just the way to validate if the field is set by user or not?

Comment: you could use `map[string]inteface{}` at some extent, but then you will have to copy over a new instance of the desired struct def. Same goes if you would use a local defined struct with proper pointers, you will still need to copy over a new instance of the desired struct def.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment @mh-cbon, I do some research about your comment, and i little bit get something more clear right now.

Comment: I am really new in go, i have little bit background in js but i think go is really different hemss.. sorry to question a something that look so bad

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `map[string]interface` may be to have a wrapping type (if possible in your case):

```
type UserWrapper {
  user     User
  ageDirty bool
}

func (u UserWrapper) SetAge(age int) {
  u.ageDirty = true
  u.user.Age = age
}

func (u UserWrapper) GetAge() int {
  return u.user.Age
}

func (u UserWrapper) AgeSet() bool {
  return u.ageDirty
}
```

It makes the intentions clearer, even if it should be better to change the structure directly